# Automatic deduction of template parameters for alias templates and template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-deduction

I want to make stateless lambda function with variadic template parameter list to be recursive. But I need type erasure to avoid errors like `variable 'lambda' declared with 'auto' type cannot appear in its own initializer`. Variadic template parameter list requires corresponding functional object to have templated `operator ()`. For simple stateless lambda function I can cast it to pointer to simple free old function, but how to achieve a similar for *variadic* stateless lambda function? I think what I want is *automatic type deduction for template parameter list* (during instantiation of template variables: during call or during assignment): (pseudocode)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

template< typename first, typename second, typename ...rest >
using fp = first (*)(first const &, second const &, rest const &...); // at least binary function

int
main()
{
    template fp sum = [] (auto const & first, decltype(first) second, auto const &... rest) { return first + sum(second, rest...); };
    //              ^ assignment                                                                                ^ call
    std::cout << sum(1, 2.0, 3.0f) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve such a behaviour currently (*C++14*) (say, using `std::function` or another way of type erasure)? Is there proposal for similar language feature? Or maybe it totally forbidden by already existent language rules?

Another possible example where it will be useful: (pseudocode)

```
template std::vector v{1, 2, 3};
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(v), std::vector< int > >{});
```

Comment: can you post example code which triggers the error you mention `variable 'lambda' declared with 'auto' type cannot appear in its own initializer` ?

Comment: @m.s. `auto lambda = [] (auto const & first, decltype(first) second, auto const &... rest) { return first + lambda(second, rest...); };` here lambda variable should be captured by default by value (the same is for `[&]` or `[&lambda]`).

Comment: For the second example, maybe [Template parameter deduction for constructors (Rev. 3)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0091r0.html) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you want. The way to deduce the result of an expression is to use `auto`. There is no way to deduce types for a function template or alias template. Consider the simplest case:

```
std::function<auto> if_this_existed = [](int x, int y) { return x + y; };
```

You probably expect `std::function<int(int, int)>`. But `std::function<void(int, int)>` works. So does `std::function<long(long, long)>`. There really is no one thing to deduce. Furthermore, for a *generic* lambda, it doesn't make sense to assign a *specific* type:

```
std::function<void(???)> print = [](auto x) { std::cout << x; };
```

The lambda can be called with any type that's printable, but whatever we put in `???` would restrict `print` to be just that type. So this fails too.

So ultimately, no, you cannot write your generic variadic lambda recursively. Although, `sum` would be impossible to write recursively anyway since you wouldn't be able to write a base case. The right way to write such a generic `sum()` would be to use a fold expression (C++1z):

```
auto sum = [] (auto const&... args) {
    return (args + ...);
};
```

Comment: Really base case is my omission, but what about second example?

Comment: @Orient I don't know what your second example is supposed to mean.

Comment: Second example mean that first template parameter of `std::vector` should be deduced so, that `std::initializer_list` constructor to be viable.

Comment: @Orient That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It is controversial conclusion.